# HTML tables stacking in outlook email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am trying to use ghost tables in order to make my responsive design work in Outlook. However, the table tds are stacking instead of displaying side by side. Help?

```
<table role="presentation" width="600" style="width:100%;max-width:600px;background-color:#1C63AA;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border:0;text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; " align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><div style="text-align:center;font-size:0;width:89%;max-width:527px;margin:23px;"> 
        <!--[if mso]>
        <table role="presentation" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="527" style="width:527px;border-collapse:collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;font-size:0;margin:23px;">
        <tr>
        <td width="264" align="left" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="width:264px;border-right:1px solid #dadada;border-collapse:collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; padding:0px;text-align:left;" align="left">
        <![endif]-->
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:263px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;border-right:1px solid #aaaaff;" align="middle">
          <p style="font-family:sans-serif;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;">text</p>
          <p style="font-family:serif; font-size: 17px;">text2</p>
        </div>
        <!--[if mso]>           
        </td>
        <td width="263" align="right" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="width:263px;border-collapse:collapse;mso-line-height-rule: exactly; padding:0px;text-align:right;" align="right">
        <![endif]-->
        <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:263px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;">
          <p style="font-family:sans-serif;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;">text</p>
          <p style="font-family:serif; font-size: 17px;">text2</p>

        </div>
        <!--[if mso]>
        </td></tr></table>
        <![endif]--> 
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't play well with divs, so the margin on it is problematic. You can shift the 23px margin onto the parent td, as padding. That also means you can make the width of the div a nice 100% instead of 89%.

i.e.

```
<td align="center" style="padding:23px;"><div style="text-align:center;font-size:0;width:100%;max-width:527px;">
```

Also, Outlook is reading both the 1px border on its table as well as the 1px border on the div, so that may be throwing you 1px out.